# Stick the footer to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footer

I need to freeze the footer panel when it's parent div reaches the bottom of the browser.

What I have tried is to make it to freeze when I scroll the page but I need it when the parent parent div reaches the bottom of the browser.

For example in my demo there is a content panel which is hidden. If you click on expand link you get to see the expanded content.

When this content expands the `bottom_content` div moves to the bottom, I need the `footer` div in it to stick to the bottom as soon as `bottom_content` is pushed down.

Here is my code currently used

```
var stickyHeaderbottom = $('.footer').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderbottom) {
            $('.footer').css({ position: 'fixed', bottom: '0px', width: '95%', left: '2.5%' });
        } else {
            $('.footer').css({ position: 'static', bottom: '0px', width: '100%' });

        }
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bonekowizuja/2/)**

Comment: Be more clear..
Stick to bottom of the page..
Or 
Bottom of the view irrespective of scrolling??...

Comment: it should stick down once the content is expanded. NOt when it scrolls down

Comment: i have edited my answer check out..

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this is what ur trying to achieve...[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hiteyibolite/1/edit)

```
$('.expandble_conetnt a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('span').slideToggle();          
    }); 

//this is for stick to the bottom
var stickyHeaderbottom = $('.footer').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderbottom) {
            $('.footer').css({ position: 'fixed', bottom:0, width: '95%', left: '2.5%' });
        } else {
            $('.footer').css({ position: 'static', bottom: $('.expandble_conetnt').offset().top, width: '100%' });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Be more clear..
Stick to bottom of the page..
Or 
Bottom of the view irrespective of scrolling??...

Comment: This looks fine but when we close the expanded content the footer should come back to the initial position.

Comment: Which means we need to target bottom_content div. When that div reached the bottom of the page, the footer should stick to the bottom of the page or it is like as it is now

Comment: As I said I cant refer expand link to get it done because there are conditions where very less content in expand div. for example http://jsbin.com/bovuhobufaqu/2/ so in this case we can not refer expand link. so I need to check the position of bottom_content div and achieve with that.